# Struggling with implementation of a type list

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

For educational purposes I want to write my own `c++11` based typelist. The bare list looks like this:

```c++
template <typename ... Ts> struct type_list;

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct type_list<T, Ts ...> {
    typedef T Head;
    typedef type_list<Ts ...> Tail;
};

template <typename T> struct type_list<T> {
     typedef T Head;
     typedef null_type Tail;
};
```

I have created a function called `front` for extracting the first element:

```c++
template <typename T> struct front;

template <typename TypeList>
struct front {
    typedef typename TypeList::Head type;
};
```

Which works as expected, i.e. this code

```c++
typedef type_list<int> lst;
typedef type_list<float,int> lst2;
typedef type_list<double,float,int> lst3;
typedef type_list<char,double,float,int> lst4;

std::cout << "front(lst1): " << typeid( front<lst>::type ).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << "front(lst2): " << typeid( front<lst2>::type ).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << "front(lst3): " << typeid( front<lst3>::type ).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << "front(lst4): " << typeid( front<lst4>::type ).name() << std::endl;
```

produces:

> front(lst1): i
> front(lst2): f
> front(lst3): d
> front(lst4): c

Naturally, a `back` function is the next step, however, I can't seem to get it to work. My code

```c++
template <typename T> struct back;

template <typename TypeList>
struct back {
    typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_same<typename TypeList::Tail, null_type>::value,
                      typename TypeList::Head,
                  typename back<typename TypeList::Tail>::type>::type type;
};
```

does not compile (`clang 3.2`) [`lst` is defined as before]:

```
TypeList.cc:33:71: error: no type named 'Tail' in 'null_type'
  typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_same<typename TypeList::Tail, null_type>::value,
                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
TypeList.cc:35:20: note:
  in instantiation of template class 'back<null_type>' requested here
    typename back<typename TypeList::Tail>::type>::type type;
    ^

TypeList.cc:54:44: note:
  in instantiation of template class 'back<type_list<int> >' requested here
    std::cout << "back(lst1): " << typeid( back<lst>::type ).name() << std::endl;
                                           ^
1 error generated.
```

---

#### Question

- Why does the `std::conditional` not trigger?

Comment: I don't think you should have `T1` and `T2`. Just one `T` should suffice.

Comment: @KerrekSB That is correct but does not solve my original problem. Nevertheless, thanks for pointing it out! I edited the code accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Improper usage of `std::conditional`

```
std::conditonal<condition, true-type, false-type>
```

Your problem boils down to that both the *true-* and *false-type* in `std::conditional` must yield a valid name, no matter which side the *condition* picks.

<sup>**Note**: There's a *proposed solution* at the end of this post if a full explanation isn't needed.</sup>

---

Consider the below example:

```
struct A { typedef int type; };
struct B { /* empty */ };
```

```
template<class T>
struct some_trait {
  typedef typename std::conditional<
    /*  condition -> */ std::is_same<T, A>::value,
    /*  true-type -> */ typename T::type,
    /* false-type -> */ void
  >::type result;
};
```

---

Instantiating `some_trait<A>` will be perfectly valid, but what happens if we instantiate it with `B`?

```
template<>
struct some_trait<B> {
  typedef typename std::conditional<
    std::is_same<B, A>::value,
    typename B::type,  // (A), ill-formed
    void
  >::type result;
};
```

In the above we are pretending to be a compiler, and we replaced every occurance of `T` with `B`, it's not all that hard work but it has raised a very important issue with our *primary-template*.

When the compiler instantiates `some_trait<T>` with `T = B`, the *true-type* in our `std::conditional` will be `B::type` *(A)*.

But since `B` has no name inside it called `type` we will get a compiler diagnostic saying that there's something wrong with our code, namely; we are trying to access a name which doesn't exist.

```
foo.cpp:15:37: error: no type named 'type' in 'B'
    /*  true-type -> */ typename T::type, // (A), ill-formed
```

---

---

#### Proposed Solution

There really is no doubt to what we have to do, and to put it in short; prevent our template from accessing names that potentially doesn't exist.

A simple way of doing this is to rely on *explicit specialization*, instead of using a `std::conditional`.

*Sample implementation of `back`*

```
template<typename TypeList>
struct back {
  typedef typename back<typename TypeList::Tail>::type type;
};

template<typename T>
struct back<type_list<T>> {
  typedef typename type_list<T>::Head type;
};
```

<sup>**Note**: If the instantiation of `template<typename T> struct back;` is a `type_list` with only one parameter, we know we are at the last node.</sup>

Comment: @dyp wording changed.

Comment: Hmm hard to come up with a concise and precise condition there. I like the change; they must indeed be valid type names (alias specializations are immediately resolved). Btw. It's a necessary but not sufficient condition, e.g. accessibility.

Comment: `typename type_list<T>::Head` is not just `T`? Why not just write `T` as result?

Comment: @Manu343726 because in this case the `type_list<T>::Head` will yield `T`, but this might not be the case for more advanced templates; better relying on the original definition so that we don't need to change the definition of `back` if `type_list` changes.

Answer (score 4):

The error results from the compiler trying to get a type name for the else part of the conditional even when the conditional evaluates to true.

You can fix that problem by creating a specialization of `back`.

```
template <typename T> struct back<type_list<T>>
{
    typedef T type;
};
```

Of course, then you can simplify the other implementation to

```
template <typename TypeList> struct back
{
    typedef typename back<typename TypeList::Tail>::type type;
};
```