# std::conditional compile-time branch evaluation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, conditional-statements

Compiling this:

```
template < class T, class Y, class ...Args >
struct isSame
{
    static constexpr bool value = std::conditional<
                                      sizeof...( Args ),
                                      typename std::conditional<
                                          std::is_same< T, Y >::value,
                                          isSame< Y, Args... >, // Error!
                                          std::false_type >::type,
                                      std::is_same< T, Y > >::type::value;
};

int main()
{
    qDebug() << isSame< double, int >::value;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Gives me this compiler error:

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2 or more)
```

The issue is that `isSame< double, int >` has an empty `Args` parameter pack, so `isSame< Y, Args... >` effectively becomes `isSame< Y >` which does not match the signature.

But my question is: Why is that branch being evaluated at all?  `sizeof...( Args )` is `false`, so the inner `std:conditional` should not be evaluated.  This isn't a runtime piece of code, the compiler *knows* that `sizeof..( Args )` will *never* be `true` with the given template types.

If you're curious, it's supposed to be a variadic version of `std::is_same`, not that it works...

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24086311/1090079) for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an error because the type has to be correct when used as template parameter.
You may use template specialization to solve your issue, something like:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename ... Ts> struct are_same;

template <> struct are_same<> : std::true_type {};
template <typename T> struct are_same<T> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Ts>
struct are_same<T1, T2, Ts...> :
    std::conditional<
        std::is_same<T1, T2>::value,
        are_same<T2, Ts...>,
        std::false_type
    >::type
{};

static_assert(are_same<char, char, char>::value, "all type should be identical");
static_assert(!are_same<char, char, int>::value, "all type should not be identical");
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid template specialisation due to it's verbosity, but in hindsight it's much more readable than what I came up with (and it works...).

Answer (score 6):

> But my question is: Why is that branch being evaluated at all?

Because there is no evaluation, and thats not a branch at all. **Thats a template and its instanced to successfully instance the `std::conditional` template**.
*What I mean here is that the evaluation abstraction is usefull when writting template metaprograms, but you should never forget what the template system is really doing*.

If you need to conditionally instantiate a potentially ill-formed template, add a level of indirection. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504860/selecting-between-valid-and-non-valid-types) answer for an example of that.

Answer (score 5):

#### Don't blame `std::conditional`

In short it's because the *template argument substitution* happens outside of `std::conditional`, which means that it's not `std::conditional` that is causing the error.. it's `isSame`.

Imagine `std::conditional` being a function call (which it isn't), what we pass as parameters are evaulated *before* the actual body of the function is evaluated, and what we pass as parameters sure must be a valid construct, even if the function itself doesn't use them.

Further reading is available in the below linked answer:

- [Improper usage of `std::conditional`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24086311/1090079)

---

#### A solution

Add some indirection so that you don't instantiate `isSame` if `sizeof... (Args) == 0`, you could have a traited used as `isSame_if_not_empty<Args..>::type` which would yield `isSame<Args...>` if `Args` is not empty, and something else if it is indeed empty.

---

#### Proposed solution

Fix so that `isSame` can be used with an empty variadic pack, yielding true, this is the sensible approach. If the description of `isSame` is *"all types passed are of the same type"*, an empty pack sure has "all of its types" of the same type.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that conditional is just a template.  Its type is dependent on all 3 parameters, even if `::type` field is only dependent on 2 of them (the `bool` and whichever it picks).

To do what you want, pass it types that represent how to apply arguments to both sides.m Then pass the arguments to the result.

```
template<template<class...>class Target>struct defer{
  template<class...Ts>using execute=Target<Ts...>;
};
template<class T>struct sink{
  template<class...>using execute=T;
};
template< class Prog, class... Ts > using run=Prog::template execute<Ts...>;

using choice = typename std::conditional< test, defer<Foo>, sink< std::false_type >  >::type;
using result = run< choice, int, double >;
```

gives us a conditional that returns a `defer`d `Foo`, or a `sink`d `false_type`.  We can then run it with some arguments, giving us either `Foo<int, double>` or `false_type`.

`sink`'s `execute` ignores the arguments and always returns the passed in type, while `defer` applies them to the passed in `template`.

The trick here is that `Foo<int, double>` is not run if `test` is false, because in that case `choice` is `sink<false_type>`!

```
template<bool b, class A, class B, class...Ts>
using pick = run< typename std::conditional< b, A, B >::type, Ts... >;

using result=pick<test, defer<Foo>, sink<std::false_type>, int, double >;
```

does the same as `choice`/`result` above in one line.

To solve your problem, we defer execution on one of your if branches:

```
static constexpr bool value =
typename std::conditional< sizeof...( Args ),
  pick< std::is_same< T, Y >::value,
    defer<isSame>,
    sink<std::false_type>,
    Y, Args...
  >,
  std::is_same< T, Y >
>::type::value;
```

now, there are often ways to avoid this technique, but you should know it exists.

Comment: Boost.MPL has `eval_if` and `identity` for delayed instantiation

Comment: @templaterex sure, but why use `boost` when writing your own metaprograms is so easy in C++11?  Back in 03, it was a pain...

Comment: Sure, but after the easy stuff you will get at a point of wanting to use general compile-time algorithms and then Boost.MPL still has advantage and your own helpers might not interoperate with it. MPL in C++14 style is still much needed IMO.